# punctuation signs in colnames are replaced by ..X

Tags: r

I am having troubles with column names containing a punctuation sign.
I diagnosed the issue as follows:

```
file <- "./spam.data.txt"
columnNames <- c('word_freq_make',       
                 'word_freq_address',               
                 ...        
                 'word_freq_table',        
                 'word_freq_conference',   
                 'char_freq_;',            
                 'char_freq_(',            
                 'char_freq_[',            
                 'char_freq_!',            
                 'char_freq_$',            
                 'char_freq_#',            
                 'capital_run_length_average', 
                  ...)
spamd <- read.table(file, sep = "" , header = F, stringsAsFactors= F,
                    col.names = columnNames)

# First look
spamd$word_freq_85         # [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
spamd$char_freq_;          # NULL
colnames(spamd)
```

The output of `colnames()` is:

```
 [1] "word_freq_make"             "word_freq_address"       ...           


[46]  "word_freq_table"            "word_freq_conference"       "char_freq_."                "char_freq_..1"             
[51] "char_freq_..2"              "char_freq_..3"              "char_freq_..4"              "char_freq_..5"              "capital_run_length_average"
```

That is, the punctuation signs in column names have been replaced by "..1", "..2", "..3", ...

Why so please?

**EDIT FOLLOWING AKRUN'S ANSWER:**

Having:

```
spamd <- read.table(file, sep = "" , header = F, stringsAsFactors= F,
                    col.names = columnNames, check.names = FALSE)
```

instead solves the renaming issue. Namely, `colnames()` now yields:

```
[41] "word_freq_cs"               "word_freq_meeting"          "word_freq_original"         "word_freq_project"          "word_freq_re"              
[46] "word_freq_edu"              "word_freq_table"            "word_freq_conference"       "char_freq_;"                "char_freq_("               
[51] "char_freq_["                "char_freq_!"                "char_freq_$"
```

But if I try `spamd$char_freq_X` where X is any punctuation mark I still get `NULL`. So, how to get access to these columns?

Thanks

Comment: rtfm `?read.table` and `?make.names`

Comment: I did not understand what you are saying sry. I m new to R.

Comment: I was just saying that this is documented behavior and you could have read that yourself by looking at the function documentation. This is available by typing a quetion mark (?) followed by the function name in your R console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `check.names=FALSE`

```
spamd <- read.table(file, sep = "" , header = F, stringsAsFactors= F,
                col.names = columnNames, check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solves the renaming issue. But, as explained in the edit,  I still cannot access columns with punctuation marks in their names. Can you tell me more abt that please?

Comment: @hartmut You can use backquotes to access those columns if you are extracting with `$` i.e. `spamd$``char_freq_X```  (use only a single backquote - forgot how to specify it in comments